# brew install FFmpeg, FFmpeg command not found on Mac v10.15.5

Tags: macos, installation, ffmpeg, homebrew

After installing FFmpeg with brew the command ffmpeg is still not found. I had to update the `~/.zshrc` to include the cellar path to the FFmpeg install. Does anyone have an explanation for why this was necessary, is there an error in the brew install script for Mac OS `10.15.5`.

Here is what my `.zshrc` now looks like:

```
userName@ComputerName-MacBook-Pro ~ % cat ~/.zshrc 
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: **homebrew** normally makes links in `/usr/local/bin` for you. So you would normally put that in your shell startup script rather than `/usr/local/sbin`

Answer (score 2):

After the feedback from Mark I did a little more digging and am now more confused as to why the link for ffmpeg is not working

```
% ls -al /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin -> /opt/local/bin
% ls -al /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg
  /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -> ../Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1/bin/ffmpeg
% ls -al /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
  /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -> ../Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1/bin/ffmpeg
% ls -al /usr/local
  Cellar (exists)
  bin -> /opt/local/bin

% ffmpeg
zsh command not found


echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

**My Solution**

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar /opt/local

% which ffmpeg
   /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```